# find the possible values of the pure resistive load to be interfaced to the PV module keeping it working at the maxi. power point (MPP)

Tags: matlab

I shoul write a MATLAB function to calculate pure resistive load (R) for different given irradiance and temperature so that a PV module (I wrote the function for that already) keeps working at its maximum powerpoint. My problem is that although I implemented the given irradiance and temperature the calculated R values are the same for every irradiance and temperature and that should not be.

Here is my written code, maybe somebody knows what I did wrong. The values for R should vary depending on the irradiance and temperature. In my code the calculated R ist always the same: 7,0977.

```
<% Given parameters
V_MPP = 36.5; % V
I_MPP = 5.1; % A
V_OC = 44.8; % V
I_SC = 5.5; % A
Pmin = 185; % W
S_STC = 1000; % Irradiance in W/m^2 under STC
T_STC = 25 + 273 % Temp. in K under STC
kv = -160; %+- 20 mV/K temp coeff of V_OC
ki = 0.00065; %(absoluter value) 0.065 +-0.015 %/K temp coeff of I_SC
kp = -0.005; %0.5 +-0.05 %/K temp coeff of P\]\]

% Calculate maximum power point
P_MPP = V_MPP \* I_MPP; % Maximum power point in W

% Given irradiance and temperature
conditions = \[250, 2 + 273; 900, 40 + 273; 900, 2 + 273; 1600, 40 + 273; 1600, 2 + 273\];

% Iterate over each condition to calculate R_MPP
for i = 1:size(conditions, 1)
S = conditions(i, 1);
T = conditions(i, 2);

    % Call PVmod to get the array of voltages and currents for given S and T
    [V, I] = PVmod(S, T); 
    
    % Calculate the power output for each voltage-current pair
    P = V .* I;
    
    % Find the maximum power (PMPP) and its corresponding voltage and current
    [PMPP, idx] = max(P);
    V_MPP = V(idx);
    I_MPP = I(idx);
    
    % Use Ohm's law to calculate pure resistive load at MPP
    R_MPP(i) = V_MPP / I_MPP;
    
    % Display R_MPP for each condition
    disp(R_MPP);

end>
```